# How to amend Google app script to search from 2 columns instead of 1 and return entire row if both columns match?

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets, excel-formula

How can I amend this app script to search from Column A and Column B?
Column A = User ID
Column B = Password

So the user must key in the User ID and Password correctly, then the matching rows will show up accordingly. If the user ID is correct, but password entered is wrong, no rows will show up.

```
    function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index')
        .evaluate()
        .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}


/* PROCESS FORM */
function processForm(formObject){  
  var result = "";
  if(formObject.searchtext){//Execute if form passes search text
      result = search(formObject.searchtext);
  }
  return result;
}

//SEARCH FOR MATCHED CONTENTS 
function search(searchtext){
  var spreadsheetIds = ['Workbook1','Workbook1'];
  var dataRages = ['Sheet1!A2:K','Sheet2!A2:K'];
  var ar = [];
  
  const colIndex = 0; // Column A

  spreadsheetIds.forEach((spreadsheetId, i) => {
    var data = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, dataRages[i]).values;        
    data.forEach(function(f) {
      if (f[colIndex] == searchtext) {
        ar.push(f);
      }
    });
  });
  return ar;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure that this is Google Spreadsheet? It looks much like MS Excel.

Answer (score 0):

First, this is tagged with Excel and Google app script / sheets.  They are not the same.

Can you provide more information, what is in formObj.searchtext?  This looks like it is taking a search term from a form, and checking if it is in Col A of either workbook.  If it is in the first column, it returns the entire row.

In order for it to check two things, you need to first get both from the formObject.

In this example, going to use the keys formObj.userId and formObj.password, you will need to change the keys to match what is passed over in the formObj.

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index')
        .evaluate()
        .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}


/* PROCESS FORM */
function processForm(formObject){  
  var result = "";
  
  // define the object values for ease of reading
  let userID = formObject.userID;
  let password = formObject.password
  
  //check if both variables have values, if so run search and pass the two variables
  if(userID && password ){
      result = search(userID, password);
  }
  return result;
}

//SEARCH FOR MATCHED CONTENTS 
function search(userID, password){
  var spreadsheetIds = ['Workbook1','Workbook1'];
  var dataRages = ['Sheet1!A2:K','Sheet2!A2:K'];
  var ar = [];
  
  // add the second column index for the password column 
  const idIndex = 0; // Column A
  const passIndex = 1; // Column B

  spreadsheetIds.forEach((spreadsheetId, i) => {
    var data = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, dataRages[i]).values;        
    data.forEach(function(f) {
      
      // for each row of data, check if the first column matches the userID 
      // AND the second column matches the password, if true, push that row into ar
      if (f[idIndex] == userID && f[passIndex]  == password) {
        ar.push(f);
      }
    });
  });
  return ar;
}
```